# Troubles with program

Tags: haskell

So i want to make a program in Haskell that goes though a list from 1 to n and every time there's a number that can be divided by 3 or 7 text appears and whenever a number can be divided by 3 and 7 it shows a text message.

Here's the code i've written, but am getting errors:

```
fuction' :: Int -> [Int]
fuction' n = take n [1..]
    | (n `mod` 3) && (n `mod` 7 == 0) = error "BoomBANG!"
    | n `mod` 3 == 0 = error " boom"
    | n `mod` 7 == 0 = error " bang"

main = do
putStrLn ("a=")
a <- readLn 
print (fuction' a)
```

Hopefully someone can tell me where my mistakes are.

Comment: what errors are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

the errors you get might be of two sources

a) the main function is incorrectly indented

```
main = do putStrLn ("a=")
          a <- readLn 
          print (fuction' a)
```

b) your function is throwing errors

```
 error "..."
```

throws an error and you should expect it.
so I guess the real answer should include some hint to get rid of the errors

```
fuction :: Int -> [String]
fuction n = take n [1..]
          | (n `mod` 3) && (n `mod` 7 == 0) = ..
          | n `mod` 3 == 0 = ..
          | n `mod` 7 == 0 = ..
          | otherwise = .. -- you forgot one case

main :: IO ()
main = do putStrLn ("a=")
          a <- readLn 
          mapM_ putStrLn (fuction a)
```

Answer (score 0):

`error` causes the program to terminate with a message. You need the program to keep running to output other messages. You can accomplish this by returning the messages from `fuction'` instead of having it try to print them itself by calling `error` to terminate the program.

We can break the program into smaller pieces. We'll import `Data.Maybe` to get `catMaybes`, which we'll use later.

```
import Data.Maybe
```

`message` determines whether to output a message for a number. Since some numbers don't have messages, we'll use `Maybe` to store either `Just "themessage"` or `Nothing`.

```
message :: Int -> Maybe String
message n | (n `mod` 3 == 0) && (n `mod` 7 == 0) = Just "BoomBANG!"
          | n `mod` 3 == 0                       = Just " boom"
          | n `mod` 7 == 0                       = Just " bang"
          | otherwise                            = Nothing
```

`messages` gets all the messages from a list of integers. `map message` computes the message for each number. `catMaybes` throws away the `Nothing`s from a list and returns a list of what was in the `Just` values.

```
messages :: [Int] -> [String]
messages = catMaybes . map message
```

`fuction'` now returns all the messages we want to output, but doesn't output them yet, saving IO for the next step

```
fuction' :: Int -> [String]
fuction' n = take n . messages $ [1..]
```

`printAll` outputs every message. `map print` makes the action to output a message for each message in the list. `sequence_` executes all the actions, discarding any result they had

```
printAll :: [String] -> IO ()
printAll = sequence_ . map print
```

The last line of `main` is changed to call `printAll` to print all the returned messages.

```
main = do
    putStrLn ("a=")
    a <- readLn
    printAll (fuction' a)
```

Comment: `fuction' n = take n . messages $ [1..]` could be `fuction' n = messages [1..n]`

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, `error` isn't for control flow, it's just for catastrophic stop-the-world problems. (Haskell is super-flexible at writing your own control structures, so you don't need that sort of thing anyway.)

### You can use `map` and `transpose`

An alternative approach to this type of problem is to run each check separately, then `transpose` the results

```
import Data.List (transpose)

ifMultipleOf n message is 
   = [if i `mod` n == 0 then message else "" | i<-is]

asSentences = unlines . map unwords
```

I'm essentially using `transpose` and `unwords` as a sort of generalised [`zipWith`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v%3azipWith).

```
boombang is = transpose 
   [map show is, ifMultipleOf 3 "boom" is, ifMultipleOf 7 "bang" is]
```

Which gives

```
ghci> boombang [1..21]
[["1","",""],["2","",""],["3","boom",""],["4","",""],["5","",""],["6","boom",""],["7","","bang"],["8","",""],["9","boom",""],["10","",""],["11","",""],["12","boom",""],["13","",""],["14","","bang"],["15","boom",""],["16","",""],["17","",""],["18","boom",""],["19","",""],["20","",""],["21","boom","bang"]]
ghci> putStrLn . asSentences $ boombang [1..21]
1  
2  
3 boom 
4  
5  
6 boom 
7  bang
8  
9 boom 
10  
11  
12 boom 
13  
14  bang
15 boom 
16  
17  
18 boom 
19  
20  
21 boom bang
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have already indicated the perils of using error. Here is another attempt at the solution using the map function and borrowing heavily from the mapM_ @AndrewC's solution but taking the map out of the IO monad. If you chose any of the other solutions, I will take my solution down.

```
function' :: Int -> [(Int, String)]
function' n = map (\x -> (x, compute x)) (take n [1..])
compute n
        | ((n `mod` 3 == 0) && (n `mod` 7 == 0)) =  "BoomBANG!"
        | n `mod` 3 == 0 =  " boom"
        | n `mod` 7 == 0 = " bang"
        | otherwise  = ""


main = do
  putStrLn ("a=")
  a <- readLn
  print (function' a)
```